# sharepoint Converting a Text Input to a Select with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i wanna convert a text input to a select with java script :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL4OI.png)

here's my script:

```js
<script>

$("#ctl00_ctl41_g_2d66c438_30c8_4364_bf9f_379b268c4b15_ASB_PS_pvtb_0").replaceWith('<select name="ctl00_ctl41_g_2d66c438_30c8_4364_bf9f_379b268c4b15_ASB_PS_pvtb_0" id="ctl00_ctl41_g_2d66c438_30c8_4364_bf9f_379b268c4b15_ASB_PS_pvtb_0">' +
        '<option value="1">Filiales</option>' +
        '<option value="2">Transport</option>' +
        '<option value="3">Events</option>' +
        '</select>');
</script>
```

i have this error :

> VM978:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replaceWith is not a function(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropdown = '<select   name="ctl00_ctl41_g_2d66c438_30c8_4364_bf9f_379b268c4b15_ASB_PS_pvtb_0" id="ctl00_ctl41_g_2d66c438_30c8_4364_bf9f_379b268c4b15_ASB_PS_pvtb_0">' +
    '<option value="1">Filiales</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Transport</option>' +
    '<option value="3">Events</option>' +
    '</select>' 

    $("#ctl00_ctl41_g_2d66c438_30c8_4364_bf9f_379b268c4b15_ASB_PS_pvtb_0").replaceWith(dropdown);

})
```

Comment: i have the same error:

VM1132:7 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replaceWith is not a function(…)

Comment: Will you check if JQuery is loaded? Also put your script in the function,

    $(document).ready(function(){

    })

Comment: yeah  J Query is not loaded , so how to load it in SharePoint page ?

Comment: i have load the j query in the master page and it work fine ,thank you user 1111,
how can we load  J Query only on one page using web part?
 thank you

Comment: You can open the page with SharePoint Designer, then add it from Designer.